# Edit appointment in Outlook reading pane

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to edit appointments in the Outlook Reading Pane?

It currently allows only to preview the appointment, but it would save a buttload of time if we wouldn't have to open and save every appointment all the time.

If not through standard settings, maybe through some reg key? Or an VBA script?

Answer (score 0):

According to my search and test, you can’t edit appointment in Outlook reading pane except subject.

You could click select appointment, then you can change subject. Like this:

[image]

P.S. Reading pane only apply for preview appointment.